# How to create album effect like this page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, image-gallery

How do I create a photo gallery like the one seen [Here](http://losangeles.kijiji.com/c-Housing-Homes-for-sale-11723-Ranchito-ST-W0QQAdIdZ167116570)?

Answer (score 1):

Couple of [examples](http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/) to get you started. You could look at their source code to figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

links containing image galleries:

[25](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/web-development/jquery-image-galleries/)

[21](http://webdeveloperplus.com/jquery/21-brilliant-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins/)

[42](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2009/09/07/42-jquery-image-gallery-plugins/)

I had these saved in my bookmarks.

some might overlap.